# Import a file and putting it inside a tuple in a particular format (python)

Tags: python, list, import, tuples

I am really stuck on this code that i've been working on and for 9 hours straight I cannot get it to work. Basically I am importing a file and splitting it to read the lines one by one and one of the tasks is to rearrange the lines in the file, for example the first line is: 34543, 2, g5000, Joseph James Collindale should look like : ['Collindale, Joseph James', '34543', g5000', '2']. So essentially it should loop over each line in the file and rearrange it to look like that format above. I created a function to check whether the length of the line is either 5 or 6 because they would both have a different format.

```
def tupleT(myLine):
     myLine = myLine.split()
     if len(myLine) == "5":
         tuple1 = (myLine[4],myLine[3],myLine[0],myLine[2],myLine[1])
         return tuple1
     elif len(myLine) == "6":
        tuple1 = (myLine[5],myLine[3]+ myLine[4],myLine[0],myLine[2], myLine[1])
        return tuple1

mylist = [] 
x = input("Enter filename: ")
try :
 f = open(x)
 myLine = f.readline()
 while (len(myLine)>0):
     print(myLine[:-1])
     myLine = f.readline()
     tupleT(myLine)
 f.close()
except IOError as e :
    print("Problem opening file")


This is what the original file looks like in textpad and its called studs.txt:
12345 2 G400 Bart Simpson
12346 1 GH46 Lisa Simpson
12347 2 G401 Homer J Simpson
12348 4 H610 Hermione Grainger
12349 3 G400 Harry Potter
12350 1 G402 Herschel Shmoikel Krustofski
13123 3 G612 Wayne Rooney
13124 2 I100 Alex Ferguson
13125 3 GH4P Manuel Pellegrini
13126 2 G400A Mike T Sanderson
13127 1 G401 Amy Pond
13128 2 G402 Matt Smith
13129 2 G400 River Storm
13130 1 H610 Rose Tyler
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: it just doesnt do anything it just prints imported file one line at a time but nothings sorted

Comment: You are returning tuple1 in your function but not assigning it in your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some commented code to get you started. Your code was a bit hard to read.

Consider renaming `first`, `second` and `third` since I have no idea what they are...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# this is more readable since there are actual names rather than array locations
def order_name(first, second, third, first_name, middle_name, last_name=None):
        if not last_name:
                # if there is no last name we got the last name in middle name (5 arguments)
                last_name = middle_name
        else:
                # if there is a middle name add it to the first name to format as needed
                first_name = "%s %s" % (first_name, middle_name)
        return ("%s, %s" % (last_name, first_name), first, third, second)

with open('studs.txt') as o:
        # this is a more standard way of iterating file rows
        for line in o.readlines():
                # strip line of \n
                line = line.strip()
                print "parsing " + line
                # you can unpack a list to function arguments using the star operator.
                print "ordered: " + str(order_name(*line.split()))
```